# How to package vagrant/Virtual box VM for loading to another system

Tags: docker, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I have a vagrant VM, and I want to create an image which I can take to another machine and then just start up the VM with all settings as it was before.

I tried doing `export appliance` and `import appliance` from Virtual Box, and I was able to start the VM, don't get vagrant so I cannot ssh into with `vagrant ssh`, and inside the VM I run a web server in docker and I cannot connect to it. The docker container does start up, but I can't connect to to.

What is the proper way to create an image of the vagrant/VirtualBox/Docker environment so that I get the entire system and can move it?

Comment: generally you would use a provisioning script to setup the VM the same way it was on the other machine. so you have vagrant base box + provisioning script  ==> always get the same VM. If your installation process is taking long or too specific, you can repackage the virtual box VM as a new box, so you start on the other system with the new box created. Check [vagrant box repackage](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/box.html#box-repackage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vagrant and VirtualBox installation will always be needed if you want to use `vagrant ssh`. They both are separate softwares. Vagrant is used for Automation of VM creation using online available images.

This make it easier to just ship source code and provisioning scripts. When one does `vagrant up` it downloads the base box online and your provisioning scripts do the necessary setup. Save you from sharing large boxes of 400MB+

When you export a VM and import it someplace else, you don't need vagrant ssh as such. The settings of the box will have some port forwarding set. Assuming `22` from guest is mapped to `2222` on host then you can ssh directly using this

```
ssh -p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1
```

Or if you had enabled host only network with a static IP then you can ssh using

```
ssh vagrant@192.168.33.100
```

PS: the password would be `vagrant` as well.